# How to keep symplecticity of a diffeomorphism after a coordinate rescaling and Taylor series expansion?

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems, symplectic-geometry

Let's take some, implicitly written, symplectic diffeomorphism $F$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, let it preserve the (possibly non-standard) symplectic form $\omega$.  Suppose I introduce a small parameter $\epsilon$ and scale one variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Scale $x$ such that $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\epsilon}$.

Naturally, $F$ would also be symplectic in the new scaled coordinate system. However, what if I use the smallness of $\epsilon$ to do a perturbative expansion of $F$ in terms of $\epsilon$, assuming that everything depends smoothly on $\epsilon$? So I write $F_{\epsilon} = F + \epsilon F_{1} + O(\epsilon^{2})$.

Does the map $F_{\epsilon}$ preserve symplecticity property, or not? If not, how could I ensure that the map indeed stays symplectic after a perturbative expansion in a small parameter?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the situation? I don't understand what is expressed in a coordinate invariant way and what is not. What do you mean by '$F$ would also be symplectic in the new scaled coordinate system'? That it is symplectic w.r.t. the 'pushforward' of the form by the rescaling? Do you define $F_{\epsilon}(x, x_2, \dots, x_{2n}) = F(x/\epsilon, x_2, \dots, x_{2n})$, which is symplectic with respect to the 'pushforwarded' form? If so, then for small $\epsilon$, you can't usually expect $F_{\epsilon}$ to be close to $F$, so that your perturbative expansion is incorrect.